# How to rotate a triangle around the circle correct?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

i have triangle around the circle and i created that If my character collides with a brick, then the triangles on the circle replacing another location on the circle.

but i have problem , the triangles rotating when its happening.

This happens when I click the screen (and thats fine) but its rotating.

it need looks like that :

[image]

but its look like that :

[image]

**AddTriangleToCircle func :**

```
func AddTriangleToCircle(Circle: SKShapeNode, Location: CGFloat, Inside: Bool) {

        Triangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Triangle.png")

        Triangle.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        Triangle.anchorPoint.y = 0



        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil,298,2)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil,149,298)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil,0,0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil,298,2)

        CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

        Triangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)


        if Inside == true {
            // Inside Triangle
            Triangle.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
        } else {
            // Outside Triangle
            Triangle.zRotation = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)
        }

        Triangle.position = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:circleRadius)

        let rotationSpeed1 = rotationSpeed + Location;
        var angleRelatedToCircle1 = angleRelatedToCircle;

        angleRelatedToCircle1 -= rotationSpeed1
        Triangle.zRotation -= rotationSpeed1

        Triangle.position.x = circleRadius * cos(angleRelatedToCircle1)
        Triangle.position.y = circleRadius * sin(angleRelatedToCircle1)


        //Triangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture:TriangelSKT, size: CGSize(width: 30, height:30))
        let centerPoint = CGPointMake(Triangle.size.width / 2 - (Triangle.size.width * Triangle.anchorPoint.x), Triangle.size.height / 2 - (Triangle.size.height * Triangle.anchorPoint.y))
        Triangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Triangle.size , center: centerPoint)
        Triangle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = triangleCategory
        Triangle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = heroCategory
        Triangle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = heroCategory
        Triangle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        // Set Dynamic to false
        Triangle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        Circle.addChild(Triangle);
    }
```

**AddCircle func :**

```
    func AddCircle() {

            Circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: circleRadius)
            Circle.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
            Circle.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            Circle.lineWidth = 9.5
            Circle.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.98, green:0.82, blue:0.32, alpha:1.0)
            self.addChild(Circle)
            Circle.addChild(BooCharacter)



            self.AddTriangleToCircle(Circle, Location: CGFloat(random(1...100)), Inside: false)
            self.AddBrickToCircle(Circle, Location: CGFloat(random(1...200)), inside: true)
            self.AddTriangleToCircle(Circle, Location: CGFloat(random(1...400)), Inside: false)


}
```

**touchsbegan func :**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

            BooCharacter.zRotation += CGFloat(M_PI)
            TapToStart.removeFromParent()

             for touch in touches {
             let location = touch.locationInNode(self)



            }

          initializeValues()    
    }
```

**initializeValues func :**

```
func initializeValues() {
    self.removeAllChildren()
    AddCircle()  
    }
```

Comment: Your "what I want" and "what I have" images are identical.

Comment: thanks you. I'm fixing this now!

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is to find two points on a circle based on an angle.

A point on a circle is found this way -

```
func pointOnCircle(radius:CGFloat, angleInRadians:CGFloat, circleCenter:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

      return CGPoint(
                 x:circleCenter.x - radius * cos(angleInRadians), 
                 y:circleCenter.y - radius * sin(angleInRadians)
      )

}
```

Don't forget to convert from degrees to radians if needed.

You need to define an angle (which defines the triangle's size) and a starting point on the circle.

Use that angle to find the other base point of the triangle on the circle with the formula, and use it again only with a smaller angle (half of the original angle probably would do fine) and a larger radius, since the third point of the triangle can be thought of as if it is located on a larger circle (the red border circle), which shares the same center point as your original circle (the green one)

[image]